How do I play audio with jQuery given a Laravel success message in my Blade template?
I've got a customer update form that returns
return redirect()->route('customer.show', $customer->id)->with('success', 'The customer has been updated successfully!');

from my controller.
Then I have the success alert in my Blade template:
        @if(session('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ session('success') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

I'm also trying to play some success audio using jQuery once the user is redirected:
<audio id="successAudio" src="{{ asset('audio/success.mp3') }}" hidden></audio>
<audio id="errorAudio" src="{{ asset('audio/error.mp3') }}" hidden></audio>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Check for success message and play success audio
        @if(session('success'))
            $("#successAudio")[0].play();
        @endif
    
        // Check for errors and play error audio
        @if($errors->any())
            $("#errorAudio")[0].play();
        @endif
    });
</script>

My problem is, the browser is giving me a NotAllowedError:
Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

How do I handle this?

Browsers block auto-play audio that isn't directly triggered by user input. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Well, I got that far. How do I still make the audio play, though? Would it work maybe with an AJAX call instead of a regular form submit.

If you start the audio as a response to the submit button click, it'll let you play it. If you start the audio asynchronously after the AJAX call comes back, it may not.
